# R Shiny: Conditional formatting selectInput items

Tags: r, shiny

When we have a all missing columns in the data frame, typically we don't want the user to select them to plot. There are many ways to do this but is it possible to let the items in the `selectInput` have conditional colors.

For example, how to let all missing column names (like the `var2` column in my sample code) in the `selectInput` item list go grey. In other words, how to rewrite the `selectInput` for us to pass in a indicator vector for the conditional formatting.

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, session, output) {

  DATA = data.frame(var1 = c(2,3,4,1,5), var2 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))

  output$select_1 = renderUI({
    variables = names(DATA)
    selectInput("select_input","select", choices = variables)

    # is.all.na.indicator = sapply(DATA, function(x) all(is.na(x))) 
    # selectInput("select_input","select", choices = variables, goGrey = is.all.na.indicator)
  }) 
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput("select_1")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Since you are dynamically generating the UI why don't you select columns to display in `selectInput` considering the NAs? I mean remove all columns that have all NAs in the select input list already.

Comment: AFAIK, options of `selectInput` can't be greyed out in any circumstances.

Comment: I know removing columns with all NAs is easy, but I just wonder if the user can see more.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, session, output) {

  DATA <- data.frame(var1 = c(2,3,4,1,5), var2 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))

  output$select_1 <- renderUI({
    variables <- variableNames <- names(DATA)
    emptyColumns <- which(sapply(DATA, function(x) all(is.na(x))))
    for(i in emptyColumns){
      variableNames[i] <- 
        sprintf("<span style='color:red;'>%s</span>", variables[i])
    }
    selectizeInput("select_input", "select", 
                   choices = setNames(variables, variableNames), 
                   options = list(render = I("
  {
    item: function(item, escape) { return '<div>' + item.label + '</div>'; },
    option: function(item, escape) { return '<div>' + item.label + '</div>'; }
  }")))
  }) 
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("select_1")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]